# Please break down the event path of a Callback Function into an ORM file

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, callback

I was tasked with creating a small application using Object Relational Mapping (ORM) for class. It's a fairly simple application, that takes client side input, places it into the database and also displays it back to the client.

However, I am having a hard time understanding the breakdown in what is happening as we pass code between 3 files. There is a `burgers-controller.js` file which requires a `burgers.js` file which requires the `orm.js` file. For anyone who wants to see the full code you can find it on my [Github](https://github.com/SavSamoylov/burger).

I get the reasoning and benefits of using an ORM and modularizing everything but I need someone to break down what is happening inside the code and in what order.

So in `burgers-controller.js` file we have the following code.

```
router.get("/", (req, res)=>{

  burgers.selectAll((result)=>{
    let handlebarsObj = {
      burgers: result
    }
    res.render("index", handlebarsObj)
  });
})
```

Then inside `burgers.js` we have the following code.

```
let burgers = {
  selectAll: (callback)=>{
    orm.selectAll("burgers",  (result)=>{
      callback(result);
    })
  }
}
```

And finally in `orm.js` we have.

```
let orm = {

  selectAll: (tableName, callback)=>{
    let queryString = "SELECT * FROM ??"

    connection.query(queryString, tableName, (err, data)=>{
      if (err){console.error("ERROR: " + err.stack)}
      callback(data)
    })
  }
}
```

The ORM file is connected to a MySQL database.

Would you explain what is happening here, and in what order?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, although its a shot in the dark since there are no indication of what the actual error is, in your description. Please forgive me if I mistakes.

The callback from `burgers-controller.js` which is sent to `burgers.selectAll(` is executed inside `burgers.js`. When its executed inside `burgers.js` and not within `burgers-controller.js` it wont have access to `res` object, which is only present in `burgers-controller.js`.

We can solve the problem using promises. I am going to use native one here, but you are free to use any other package (eg: [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird)):

```
// burgers-controller.js
router.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    burgers
        .selectAll()
        .then((result) => {
            let handlebarsObj = {
                burgers: result
            }
            res.render('index', handlebarsObj)
        })
})

// burgers.js
let burgers = {
    selectAll: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            orm.selectAll('burgers', (result) => {
                resolve(result)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

You can use promises everywhere are deal with failures more gracefully:

```
// burgers-controller.js
router.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    burgers
        .selectAll()
        .then((result) => {
            let handlebarsObj = {
                burgers: result
            }
            res.render('index', handlebarsObj)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            let errMsg = {
                message: err.message,
                error: err
            }
            res.render('index', errMsg)
        })
})

// burgers.js
let burgers = {
    selectAll: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            orm
                .selectAll('burgers')
                .then((result) => {
                    resolve(result)
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    reject(err)
                })
        })
    }
}

// orm.js
let orm = {
    selectAll: (tableName) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let queryString = "SELECT * FROM ??"

            connection.query(queryString, tableName, (err, data)=>{
                if (err) {
                    console.error("ERROR: " + err.stack)
                    reject(err)
                } else {
                    resolve(data)
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```